# "Invalid Element" AXIS error while calling web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

We are calling a web service where `RequestDetails` is an input object and getting the following error. I've read at multiple forums that the "invalid element"-related error occurs if there is a mismatch between the field at the client and webservice sides. Can anyone shed more light on this?

```
55-a002-d59e5869552f|884ce533-9236-42e0-bb2c-93beeefddc38|en_GB - xyzabc|m023}
12:15:21,784 [ebContainer : 1] ERROR      : oteservice.impl.m023.SendwantRequestExt: Requesting want failed. AxisFault thrown. {JQU|||||c86d4f9c-a493-4e5a-a2ce-d52bee2128b5|884ce533-9236-42e0-bb2c-93beeefddc38|en_GB - xyzabc|m023}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid element in com.ABC.wm.eu.webserviceapp.ejb.ws.RequestDetails - standardField
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:512)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:416)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
        at com.ABC.applica.v1.privateservices.orderentrytreasurymanagement.extension.wantservice.impl.m023.ws.LocalServiceStub.requestwant(LocalServiceStub.java:773)
        at com.ABC.applica.v1.privateservices.orderentrytreasurymanagement.extension.wantservice.impl.m023.SendwantRequestExt.sendwantRequest(SendwantRequestExt.java:183)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
```

Answer (score 2):

Found out what the cause was. The field `standardField` was missing from the input class `RequestDetails`.